# Using JS to sum a column of values from an external text file containing donation histories of a db of donors

Tags: javascript

I need some assistance figuring out how to sum a column of dynamic totals that could be a positive or negative dollar amount, or an indication of stock shares.

I have a tab-delimited text file of donor contributions for that I am matching up against a CSV file of other related customer data that I am using to create a statement letter which will show a "donation history" of a particular donor. Each donor has a different amount of donations, and to complicate things, the column of data for a particular donation record could show either "**$1,000.00**" or "**($1,000.00)**" or "**2 Shares APPL**". The number with the parentheticals is of course, representing a negative number.

At the end of this column, I need to show a string that will read either "**Total: $1,000.00**," or if any of the donation history contains a donation record that included shares of stock the returned string will simply read, "**$1,000.00 & Stock**."

I have been racking my brain trying to come up with the JS rule that can achieve this. I have the JS rule that is generating the donation history correctly, but summing the donation amount column is causing me to go crazy...

Here is the JS for generating my donation history list in the letter (this seems to be working fine):

```
var contributionList = new ExternalDataFileEx("/~wip/248839 Frontiers/Master Data/Double Data proof.txt", "\t");
var donor_id = Field("Supporter");
var lb = "<br>\n";
var matches = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i <= contributionList.recordCount; i++) {

    var idVariable = contributionList.GetFieldValue(i, "Supporter");
    var dateVariable = contributionList.GetFieldValue(i, "Donation Date");
    var ministryVariable = contributionList.GetFieldValue(i, "Ministry Designation");
    var giftVariable = contributionList.GetFieldValue(i, "Donation Amount");
    var tsSettings = "<p tabstops=19550,Right,,;29600,Left,,;>";
    var ts = "<t>";

    if (donor_id == idVariable)
    matches.push(tsSettings + dateVariable + ts + giftVariable + ts + ministryVariable);
}

//return matches;

return matches.join(lb);
```

Now here is the JS code that is **not** working just fine. I am trying to tally the donation amount column, it only returns "Total: $0.00 & Stock" every time (I have tried to explain my thought process via comments):

```
var contributionList = new ExternalDataFileEx("/~wip/248839 Frontiers/Master Data/Double Data proof.txt", "\t");
var donor_id = Field("Supporter");

for (var i = 0; i <= contributionList.recordCount; i++) {

    var idVariable = contributionList.GetFieldValue(i, "Supporter");
    var giftVariable = contributionList.GetFieldValue(i, "Donation Amount");
    var sum = 0;
    var shares = 0;
    var tsSettings = "<p tabstops=19550,Right,,;29600,Left,,;>";
    var ts = "<t>";
    var totalStr = "Total ";
    var stockStr = " & Stock";
    var totalFormatted = FormatNumber("$#,###.00", Math.max(0, StringToNumber(sum)));

// Match data from linked file to current Supporter
    if (donor_id == idVariable) {

    // Look at current record and see if it contains the word "Share(s)"
    // or not and act accordingly
        if (giftVariable.match(/(^|\W)share($|\W)/i) || giftVariable.match(/(^|\W)shares($|\W)/i)) {
        // Turn switch "on" if donation amount is a share or shares so
        // we can have the " & Stock" appended to our string.
            shares = 1;
        // Because this donation is/are shares, we must "zero" this
        // amount to make the math work when we sum everything up...
            giftVariable = 0;
        // This is where we are keeping our running total...
            sum += giftVariable[i];
        } else {
        // This record was not a donation of share(s) so we now have to
        // determine whether we are dealing with postive or negative numbers
        // and then strip out all of the non-number characters, remove and
        // replace the () whis just a "-," leaving us with a number we can
        // work with...

        // If number has parenthesis, then deal with it...
            if (giftVariable.indexOf("(")) {
            // Strip out all the ()$, characters...
                giftVariable = giftVariable.replace(/[()$,]/g,"")
            // Append the minus sign to the number...
                giftVariable = "-" + giftVariable;
                sum += giftVariable[i];
            } else {
            giftVariable = giftVariable.replace(/[$,]/g,"");
            sum += giftVariable[i];
            }

        }

    }

}

// Return Total...
if (shares == 1) {
    return tsSettings + totalStr + ts + totalFormatted + stockStr;
} else {
    return tsSettings + totalStr + ts + totalFormatted;
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI `or` is not a javascript conditional (should use `||`). I would track the number of shares and the running cash total separately and concatenate them at the end.

Comment: I would agree, but that is not how our client is providing the data to us unfortunately. I updated the code to show the correct conditional, I had previously fixed that in my code but not in this version that I had posted here. Thank you @JDunken.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (and code) needs to be broken into smaller, atomic steps. From your description it sounds like you should:

```
load a text file into memory

for each line in the file
   extract: {
      donor_id
      charity
      gift
   and store the results in a contributions dictionary

for each item in the contributions dictionary
   transform gift string into {
      dollarAmount: float with a default of 0.0
      stock: name with a default of ""
   }

create an empty dictionary called totals
each item will have the shape {
   id
   dollarAmount as a float
   stocks an an array
}

for each item in the contributions dictionary
lookup the id in the totals dictionary
if it exists
   totals[id].dolarAmount += item.dollarAmount
   totals[id].stocks.push(item.stock)
otherwise
   totals[id].dollarAmount = item.dollarAmount
   totals[id].stocks = [item.stock]

normalize your charities
for each item in totals dictionary
   remove any empty strings from item.charities

create your report
for each item in totals dictionary
   write`${item.id} donated `${item.dollarAmont}` ${item.stocks.length > 1 ? 'and stock' : ''
```

I believe you are trying to do too many things at once. Instead, the goal should be to normalize your data before you attempt to perform any calculations or aggrgrations, then normalize your aggregrations before writing your summaries or reports.

I would also stay away from using any direct string manipulation. You should have a dedicated function whose only purpose is to take a string like "($20.34) and 1 share of APPL" and return either  20.34, -20.34, or 0.0. And a *different* function whose only purpose is to take the same string and return either `true` or `false` is stock was present.

Comment: Thank you BrianHVB, this is JS that is being used in a Variable Data Printing plugin scenario for Adobe Acrobat for a super hot-rush job. I am limited with what I can do in this environment that I am working in, time, and experience, but I will try to incorporate and implement what I can... for future jobs.